# Build "WPF application" as x86 and x64 at same build event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

***Requirement:***
An existing WPF application is built as x64 exe, The requirement is to build it as a x86 exe as well. I should not configure it to build as "Any CPU". The build event should generate "x86" and "x64" executables.

***Tried:***
I have created a new WPF project which targets x86 platform and added the files from the existing project using "Add as link", which would prevent multiple copies of the same files.

*Problem with this approach:* Since it is a WPF project it links *.xaml.cs to corresponding *.xaml, When i add these files using "Add as link", *.xaml.cs is not under the corresponding *.xaml. Therefore it does not build the x86 executable. This would have worked if the project did not contain any xaml files which is evident from multiple answers given in stackoverflow.

Finally, Is there a way that i can build a "WPF application" as x86 and x64 in the same build event?
am i missing something in the approach i have tried?

Comment: No, "build event" does not make enough sense.  Use Build > Batch Build to build for more than one platform at the same time.  Keep in mind that this is only sensible for the final release build since you are never going to debug them at the same time.   Automating that is not terribly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach to solve this is to using **build configurations and platforms**. When building a project, a set of configuration parameters is used. You can not only have one configuration but as many as you like. Usually, a project is generated with a Debug and a Release configuration.

In addition, you can also define platforms that contain the parameters that are relevant for a specific platform. A WPF project is initially generated with the "Any CPU" platform, but you can easily add platforms that fit your needs.

When building a project, a configuration and a platform is selected. If you want to build for two platforms, you should build twice and change the platform for the second build.

The starting point to configure build configurations and platforms is the **configuration manager** (Menu *Build* -> *Configuration Manager*). You can use this dialog to create build configurations and platforms and choose which project configurations are used when building a specific solution configuration.

After you have set up the required configurations and platforms, you can change the settings in the **project properties**. At the top of the window you can select the build configuration and platform that you are editing.